# cout does not name a type

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and I'm on the "hello  world" program and I keep getting the error

"cout" does not name a type I'm using geany on Ubuntu if that makes a difference and here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
extern cout << "hello world!";
    return 0;
}
```

I  don't want to make a new question so I'm going to add it here

With the revisions supplied it will compile now, but when i run  the program i get the error

```
./geany_run_script.sh: 5: ./geany_run_script.sh: ./hello: not found
```

any ideas on that?

Comment: You either need `std::cout`, or a `using namespace std;` after the `#include`.

Comment: i think you need to specify the namespace `std`: `using namespace std` before main() or `std::cout`

Comment: Please don't use (or advise) `using namespace std;` we all know the mess it makes in the end. :( Just use the `std::` prefix everywhere you need it.

Comment: As per @syam comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065

Answer (score 3):

Change `extern` to `std::`. The first problem is that `extern` is only valid before the name of a type, so that's what the compiler is complaining about. The second is that `cout` is defined in the namespace `std`, so you need to tell the compiler to look there. The good thing is that the code doesn't say `using namespace std;`.

Comment: i added the extern as an attempt to see if that would solve it

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
extern cout << "hello world!";
```

too

```
std::cout << "hello world!";  // You probably want \n on the end.
```

This is because `cout` is an object defined in the namespace `std`. Thus you need let the compiler know where to find it by prefixing it with `std::`. There are a couple of alternative techniques but this is the best in my opinion.

Alternative one: Use the `using directive`

```
using std::cout;
cout << "hello world!";
```

The `using std::cout;` tells the compiler that there is an object in `std` called `cout` that we want to use locally and it is brought into the current context thus allowing you to use it directly.

Comment: i removed the \n to see if that would help and can you explain the std : : thing please?